# Multigraph definition confusion

Tags: graph-theory, definition, multigraphs

I've started *Graphs, Algorithms, and Optimizaton* by Kocay and Kreher. They describe a multigraph as having more than one edge between the same end point vertices. . .

> . . . an edge can then no longer be defined as a pair of vertices (or
>   the multiple edges would not be distinct), but to each edge there
>   still correcsponds a pair $\{u,v\}$. We can express this formally by
>   saying that a graph $G$ consists of a vertex set $V(G)$, and edge set
>   $E(G)$, and a correspondence $\psi : E(G) \rightarrow (\frac{V(G)}{2})$. Given an edge $e \in E(G)$, $\psi(e)$ is a pair
>   $\{u,v\}$ which are the *endpoints* of $e$. Different edges can then
>   have the same endpoints.

I guess I don't understand what the $\rightarrow$ is doing. They don't mean adjacency, do they? The $(\frac{V(G)}{2} )$ is the set of all vertex pairs, right? Earlier it said $E(G) \subseteq (\frac{V(G)}{2}) $, that is, the edge set and the vertex set respectively, where the edge set is a subset or equal to all the vertex pairs. How does this $\psi$ definition allow us to define multiple unique edges per vertex pair?

Comment: $\psi$ is a function from from the set of edges to set of vertex pairs. This allows multiple edges because more than one edge can be mapped to the same pair of vertices.

Comment: The map $\psi$ is just telling that each edge in $E(G)$ still has two end points.